# Is follow-ups the right word?

Tags: synonyms

I'm creating a web page (intranet) where administrators can add customers to scheduled "follow-ups" by phone (we'll call them in the future and ask how it goes). So I used google translate and the web to find a good word for my menu tab. When using Google Translate I got "follow-ups" as a suggestion. This don't seem appropiate enough to me, so is there synonyms or better word for my purpose? Or is it the right word?

Comment: We use *follow-ups* on our intranet and it works just fine. (In your case, the more specific *callback* will work, but our follow-ups can be by email, fax, or in person.) Anyway, the thing is you always write for an *audience*, and in your case, the audience is your own colleagues. So in point of fact, you can use *whichever word you agree upon*. Absolutely any word you like. Could be *Jabberwocky*, as long as it's understood. In fact you'd be well advised, rather than asking here, to ask your colleagues first. It might well be they already are using *Jabberwocky* (or *follow-ups*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps **[callbacks](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/callback)**

> a return call

Also often found as *[call-back](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/call-back?r=66)*.

Answer (score 1):

*Follow-ups* sounds okay, but if you don't like it then how about *follow-up calls*?